# Is it required to click I Understand?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

Some days ago I was in the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) tab. I accidentally clicked on Approve which was a challenge, and I failed! Before that, I clicked I understand, but this time I just went back to the main page, and when I came back I was seeing this error!

[image]

I wanted to ask, is it necessary to click on the **I Understand** button? Is it some sort of button to keep me safe from such blocks?

Comment: +1. Cos I remember this happened to me too and now, I'm banned for 2 days

Comment: hehehe yeah, this isn't fair! Because anyone can skip this..

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan How exactly is it not fair?

Comment: No I mean, if it is all because of the bad reviews than it is 100% right! But if it is because I didnot clicked on I understand, then it is not fair! However, as Anna has answered this seems fair :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you don't have to click "I Understand". Only the audit failures themselves are considered when determining if a user should be blocked from reviewing for a while.

Comment: It's ratio of success to failures isn't it?

Comment: Oh, nice answer! :) And supportive too :) Thanks..