# What happens when I click: I do understand?

Tags: feature-request, disputed-review-audits

This is a followup to [Is it required to click I Understand?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211305/is-it-required-to-click-i-understand) which Anna answered with:

> Only the audit failures themselves are considered when determining if a user should be blocked from reviewing for a while

I would like to know if there's any other mechanic behind any of the "I understand" buttons?

Or, phrased in stronger terms: Let's have a "I disagree with this audit" button to temporarily remove a post from the audit queue, put it back in review queues, and only after it got reviewed again with a confirmative result, add it back to the audit queue.

Or, maybe the "disagree" button could remove it and flag it for moderator review?

Or, that button could automatically create a corresponding meta post?

There are plenty of meta questions about "why did this audit fail". Some are legitimate, some are not. A button to signal disagreement with the audit could help and accelerate in the process or clarification.

Comment: Found a related / duplicate proposal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188780/245360.

Comment: @Patrick: You have found such a complete discussion on the topic of my question, that I will close mine here, even though it is not an exact duplicate. Good answers there, too. So I'd rather "bundle" the up/downvotes there. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. Funny: If I close vote with a duplicate my own question, it still needs <n> more reviewers. Strange.

Comment: Indeed, but there is a new header you can click. The it gets closed instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if there's any other mechanic behind any of the "I understand" buttons?

No, it just moves you to the next review item. While the text might be controversial, the *I understand* button actually forces you to read the message. That's all.

> Let's have a "I disagree with this audit" button...

Currently review items aren't reused that often, so putting them in a queue to be reviewed is quite pointless. The reason that post was picked was of the post score. If you think it is wrong, act accordingly on the post. If you have to: up-vote, down-vote, close-vote, etc. That will remove the post from the queue most likely very soon.